# Can I use negative binomial regression to measure intensity of mobile money adoption through using transactions?

Tags: econometrics

Is negative binomial regression suitable to measure intensity of mobile money adoption through using transactions?

Comment: Negative binomial is typically used when you have a non-negative count variable as an outcome. E.g., an outcome that takes values 0,1,2,... 
To answer your question, we'll need you to describe the data you have.